# Count of null values in all columns in total

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have 100 columns where want to find null values in all column in total.

[image]

`FindNull` functon helps me to convert `'null'`to '1' to be able to count them

[image]

Here is my code:

```
       (select totalAmountOfNull = 
               (select  count(*) from (select 
 countOfNull=
                            [dmt].[findNull](column1) + 
                            [dmt].[findNull](column2) + 
                            [dmt].[findNull](column3) )
                            from dmt.tableName ) as t10 where t10.totalAmountOfNull = 3
```

And Answer is wrong, due to '3'. The Main problem is that I do have 100 columns in one table and want to find all null values in total. But this code gives me wrong number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use `apply`:

```
select count(*)
from t cross apply
     (values (t.col1), (t.col2), (t.col3), . . . ) v(col)
where v.col is null;
```

You need to list all the columns in the `values()` clause.